# Accessing data from array of structs containing arrays

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This is a follow on to a previous question I asked on Array of Structs Containing Arrays. Thanks to SO help I was able to get an array of structs containing arrays initialized from a separate byte array of data.

The intent of the code I'm working on is to take in byte data, eventually from a network source, that represents packets of waveform samples structured as in the WVsamps struct declaration.

I need to accumulate these in an array of said structs so I can plot waveforms in realtime and also go back and review waveform history and make measurements. The ldSamps array needs to be sized so in can accept up to 0x40000 Wvsamps structs. The samples arrive at 1 Wvsamps struct size packet/sec.

Here's the WVsamps struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe public struct Wvsamps
{
    const int Size = 3;
    fixed ushort wav1[Size];
    fixed ushort wav2[Size];
    fixed ushort wav3[Size];
    fixed ushort wav4[Size];
    public ushort modes;
    public uint time;
    public ushort chkSum;
}
```

It reads in data from a byte array such as this which for now simulates data in a buffer received over a network connection:

```
namespace ScrollWave
{
    public static class waveData
    {
        public static byte[] wvSamps = 
        {
            0x94, 0xa5, 0xca, 0x62, 0x41, 0x28, 0x4c, 0x93, 0x09, 0x42, 0x00, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x04, 0x01, 0x40, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x0d, 0x58, 0x3e, 0xc6, 0xd1, 0x07, 0x9c, 
            0x94, 0xa3, 0x8a, 0x62, 0x41, 0x29, 0x4c, 0x94, 0xc9, 0x32, 0x00, 0x24, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x04, 0x01, 0x40, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x0d, 0x58, 0x3e, 0xc6, 0xd2, 0x08, 0x0c, 
...etc.
```

Here is how I read data into my array of structs containing arrays (just doing 32 structs now for testing):

```
namespace ScrollWave
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Wvsamps[] ldSamps = new Wvsamps[0x40000];                   // 72.8 hours worth of Wvsamps structs in ldSamps[] array
            int wvSampIndx = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)                                // take 32 lines of wvSamps data and put into Wvsamps structs in ldSamps array
            {
                Wvsamps sample = new Wvsamps();
                //wav1 = [1,2,3]
                sample[0, 0] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];          // || waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[0, 0] <<= 8;                                     // make bytes to shorts
                sample[0, 0] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                sample[0, 1] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[0, 1] <<= 8;
                sample[0, 1] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                sample[0, 2] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[0, 2] <<= 8;
                sample[0, 2] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                //wav2 = [1,2,3]
                sample[1, 0] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[1, 0] <<= 8;
                sample[1, 0] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                sample[1, 1] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[1, 1] <<= 8;
                sample[1, 1] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                sample[1, 2] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[1, 2] <<= 8;
                sample[1, 2] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                //wav3 = [1,2,3]
                sample[2, 0] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[2, 0] <<= 8;
                sample[2, 0] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                sample[2, 1] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[2, 1] <<= 8;
                sample[2, 1] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                sample[2, 2] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[2, 2] <<= 8;
                sample[2, 2] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                //wav4 = [1,2,3]
                sample[3, 0] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[3, 0] <<= 8;
                sample[3, 0] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                sample[3, 1] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[3, 1] <<= 8;
                sample[3, 1] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                sample[3, 2] = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample[3, 2] <<= 8;
                sample[3, 2] |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                //modes
                sample.modes = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample.modes <<= 8;
                sample.modes |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                //time
                sample.time  = (uint)waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++] << 24;
                sample.time |= (uint)waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++] << 16;
                sample.time |= (uint)waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++] << 8;
                sample.time |= (uint)waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                sample.chkSum = waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];
                sample.chkSum <<= 8;
                sample.chkSum |= waveData.wvSamps[wvSampIndx++];

                Console.WriteLine("{0:X04}, {1:X04}, {2:X04}, {3:X04}, {4:X04}, {5:X08}, {6:X04} ", sample[0, 0], sample[1, 0], sample[2, 0], sample[3, 0], sample.modes, sample.time, sample.chkSum);
            }

            // how would I access ldSamp.Wvsamps sample data here or in another method when I'm outside of the above for (::) loop?
            // ....
            //
        }
```

While I'm inside the for(;;) loop that is loading data from the wvSamps byte array into the ldSamps array of WVsamps structs I can access and send to the console the WVsamps struct elements verifying they are correctly set.

When I'm outside of the for(;;) loop I can't figure out how to access a WVsamps struct elements at a specific ldSamps array location.

Follow on question:

What I trying to do is create a product in WinForms that I had previously as an embedded product running on custom hardware with code written in C/C++. I've been trying to emulate my algorithms and approaches from C/C++ in C#. Perhaps there is a more suitable approach to do this in C# and I'm trying to pound a square peg into a round hole. Would Lists or Dict or something else be better suited to solving this instead of sticking with Arrays of Structs containing Arrays?

Comment: In your for loop... where are you putting each "sample" object into the `IdSamps` array? I see your creation for each new `sample` then you print them out, but you are not saving them. Are you missing at the end of the loop something like: `ldSamps.Add(sample);`?

Comment: Good question, I'm new to C# so I'm not familiar with that syntax. How and in what context would I use it? I assumed by virtue of the Wvsamp[] ldSamps = new Wvsamps[0x40000]; declaration they were all created and I was just saving values into the structs. Do I need something more?

Comment: I am pretty sure the line `Wvsamps[] ldSamps = new Wvsamps[0x40000];` creates the array of `Wvsamps` objects, but it is simply an empty storage device until you put some `Wvsamp` objects into it. I am guessing you could add an index for this array and simply add each `sample` into the array. Example: before your for loop, add `index = 0` then at the end of the for loop add `ldSamps[index] = sample` then increment the index with `index++`. As I said you are creating the array but you are not using it to save each sample.

Comment: One other question... Are you able to compile this code? I would think you would get indexing errors at the lines: `sample[0, 0]`

Comment: Yes, the code compiles and runs. I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Adding the index worked and I'm able to access elements of the ldSamps outside of the for{;;} loop. Can you tell me how I can access ldSamps from other methods in the Form? I tried using smpIdxLabel.Text = ldSamps[indx++].time.ToString(X04) but I get an error while coding that says "the name ldSamps does not exist in the current context". Also, sorry but I don't know how to highlite/format code blocks in my comments. When I use CTRL+K it causes my browser to open a new tab.

Comment: @JohnG Ok, I just figured it out and moved the Wvsamps[] ldSamps = new Wvsamps[0x40000]; before Form1(). Still can't figure out how to highlite code in my comments though.

Comment: Glad you got it working. To highlight code for bold, italic, links... click on the help to right of the comment window. There is limited formatting in comments but the help should get you started. Again glad you got it working, I am not familiar with how you are setting up your struct `Wvsamps` as it appears to need the unsafe qualifier. But if it works for you then that is all that matters.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, it needs the unsafe qualifier and 'Allow unsafe code' must be checked in the project properties. I'm redoing my Wvsamps to eliminate the arrays and declare each sample as a short. It seems C# is rather unfriendly for using arrays within structs.

Comment: I am just guessing but I would think that `Wvsamps` should be a class by itself. And your wav1, wav2...arrays as lists. I would think this would make things easier. Just a thought.